# HRef Based on LogIn Access Level

Tags: php, html

After Login, when on IndexPage_AfterLogin.php, there is a dynamic navbar that gives some options to the loggedin user.

On one of those links I want the Href to send people to 3 different pages considering their access level.

HTML example:

```
<?php 

if (isset($_SESSION['nivelacessoUtilizador']) && $_SESSION['nivelacessoutilizador'] == 1);
    {?>

    <a href="info_socio.php"> Informações </a>;

    <?php }

elseif(isset($_SESSION['nivelacessoUtilizador']) && $_SESSION['nivelacessoUtilizador'] == 2);

{?>

<a href="info_admin.php"> Informações </a>';

<?php } else  {?>

<a href="info_superadmin.php"> Informações </a>';
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Can you explain what's happening since it's not what you expect? Is everyone getting sent to `info_superadmin.php`?

Comment: Missing session_start(); ?

Comment: I have session start on top of the page and yes, everyone is getting info_superadmin.php....
And now i'm getting an error somewhere on those lines... "elseif not expected"..

Comment: The last is because you're terminating the `if` with a semicolon: `if (isset(... == 1); ` <---, which ends the sentence

Comment: I hope you're not solely basing your user control on showing/hiding links.....that's a very easily defeated security strategy!

Comment: Thanks Damien. Took it out and everyone is going to superadmin again.